# SMB3 on centos fluctuating read/write speeds

Tags: centos6, 10gbethernet, smb-conf

I recently got two 10GbE cards and have been testing a SMB share from centos 6.4 with it as the SMB server.

The SMB client end is a Mac and I don't seem to be maximizing the network speed because it seems to be fluctuating when I look at the System Monitor on Centos.

I've tried modifying the smb.conf but it doesn't seem to change the dilemma.

Here's what I have tried so far on smb.conf

socket options = TCP_NODELAY IPTOS_LOWDELAY SO_RCVBUF=131072 SO_SNDBUF=131072
dns proxy = No
max protocol = SMB3

Maybe cos SMB is single threaded?.... But even if it is, my CPU load doesn't go above 50% for that single CPU load as shown in System Monitor.

Here's my system monitor image, you can see it really fluctuates up and down in the network history.

[Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfZ2C.jpg)

Comment: Okay so after doing a yum update the system monitor network history seems to not fluctuate anymore. However, I am only getting 360 MiB/s... not sure what the cap is.

Comment: It may be worth trying the native Windows SMB implementation on hardware server or inside KVM. Samba is still far from being perfect without proper SMB-direct (RDMA) support along with SMB multipath issues. Here's a nice article describing deployment of free SMB 3 file server on top of Hyper-V server 2012 (not really production-ready as it violates MSFT licensing policy but perfect for internal testing): https://slog.starwindsoftware.com/smb3-0-fileserver-on-free-microsoft-hyper-v-server-2012r2/